# With crypto.js, do I need to store the initialization vector and re-use it for decryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptojs

I am encrypting files received from clients on an app backend. I use a random byte array for an initialization vector, generate a key, encrypt and store the file using AES-256-CTR, encrypt the key with the client's public key and return it to them. I store the key on my end.

My question is, if I want to decrypt the file, do I need to store the initialization vector from the above step?

Comment: The data decryption piece looks like this: 
```
        const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', decryptedKey, iv, null);
        const input = fs.createReadStream(inputFilePath);
        const output = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(outputFilePath, fileName));
```

The question is, do I need to save the iv from the encryption and pass it in here.

Comment: When decrypting, you must use the IV that was used during encryption. So you have to store the IV that was applied during encryption. The IV is not secret, hence it is usually concatenated with the ciphertext. The decrypting side separates both parts based on the known length of the IV.